# Get XElement.Value on multiple elements by element name

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this code:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XElement xe = xdoc.Root.Element("program");

string[] data = new string[3];

XElement element = xe.Element("name");
data[0] = element.Value;

element = xe.Element("version");
data[1] = element.Value;

element = xe.Element("beta");
data[2] = element.Value;

return data;
```

Is it possible to write something like this instead:

```
xe.Element["name"].Value
xe.Element["version"].Value
```

I know I can't write exactly like that, but is their any method that works like that one?
So that I get rid of some lines and makes the process faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use the right kind of brackets, for the method call instead of indexer syntax...

```
return new string[] {
    xe.Element("name").Value,
    xe.Element("version").Value,
    xe.Element("beta").Value
};
```

Comment: Sweet. Thank you!
lol when thinking over it, I feel so stupid even asking this :>

Comment: Can I get the values like xe.Element("name\version") like this?

Comment: @RohitVyas: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve by that, but I strongly suspect not.

Comment: @jon Skeet , actually my scenario is like For example my xml is like <root><item><value><1>a</1><2>b</2><value></item></root>  so if I want to get the the list of all element inside value tag how I can get this?

Comment: @RohitVyas: It sounds like you should really be asking a new question, but `doc.Root.Element("item").Element("value").Elements()`

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your answere, this is what I exactly I want but level of nodes, means "value" node inside "item" node is customize in our application so as per setting i have to read the node, it is not neccessary that every time value node present in item node, that is why i was looking for somethig like "item\value" this string I can create as per setting...I hope you understand my probelm.